# Square up FLOW navigation

Tags: android, dagger-2

I followed [Lukaspili Demo](https://github.com/lukaspili/Mortar-Flow-Dagger2-demo) to create MVP architecture project for Motor & Flow framework integration. I want to have two different activities with for before login  &  after login. I am not able to get parent activity instance to create the new Intent(ParentActivity.this, NewActivity.class). Is any one faced this situation?

Comment: Which version of Flow? 1.0.0-alpha or 0.12?

Comment: Oh, it's Flow 0.10. That was a while ago... let me figure that out

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: Its Flow 0.12

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to obtain the Activity as the `base context` of your view.

```
public static Activity getActivity(Context context) {
    if(context instanceof Activity) {
        return (Activity) context;
    } else if(context instanceof ContextWrapper) {
        Context baseContext = ((ContextWrapper) context).getBaseContext();
        if(baseContext instanceof Activity) {
            return (Activity) baseContext;
        }
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "No activity could be found in [" + context + "]");
    throw new IllegalStateException("No activity could be found in [" + context + "]");
}
```

Comment: Presenter only holds the View context. Hence we cant get the activity context via above method. We need to achieve via Dagger scope.. But, I am struggling to get it

Comment: You should be able to extract the Activity context from the View context using this method. Please try it. But if the base context is **not** an Activity, then I'll try to figure something out. This method would not work in Flow 1.0.0-alpha.

Comment: I am using Flow 0.12 Only . I got the error message "No activity could be found in [flow.path.PathContext@7e92cf1]" .

Comment: Oh wait you're absolutely correct... >.> I resolved back then this previously by setting the Activity in a field in the `BasePath` I had, and it was set to `null` when the navigation cleared it out (in the `Flow.Dispatcher`). This was a problem even in the new Flow version, but if you can somehow fork Flow 0.12 then [delegating the Activity-specific context methods and allowing the extraction of the Activity from the internal Flow context (PathContext)](https://github.com/Zhuinden/flowless/blob/master/flowless-library/src/main/java/flowless/InternalContextWrapper.java) fixes this problem.